# Snow Leopard NFS Server and no_root_squash

Tags: mac-osx, nfs, osx-snow-leopard

I want to export an NFS share from my Mac to a linux VMware, but I'm running into a problem with the export.

Things work fine when I export as:

```
/Users/garyrichardson/leap/nfs -rw 172.16.180.130

Macintosh-3:~ garyrichardson$ showmount -e
Exports list on localhost:
/Users/garyrichardson/leap/nfs      172.16.180.130
```

But if I try to use `no_root_squash`, the mount doesn't show up:

```
/Users/garyrichardson/leap/nfs -rw 172.16.180.130(no_root_squash)

Macintosh-3:~ garyrichardson$ showmount -e
Exports list on localhost:
```

Am I using the wrong syntax? Is no_root_squash not support under snow leopard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found my solution in `man exports` on the mac:

> -maproot=user:group1:group2:... The colon separated list is used to
>   specify the precise credential to be
>   used for remote access by root. The
>   elements of the list may be either
>   names or numbers.  Note that ``user:''
>   should be used to distinguish a
>   credential containing no groups from a
>   complete credential for that user.

which leads to:

> In the absence of -maproot and -mapall
>   options, remote accesses by root will
>   result in using a credential of -2:-2.
>   All other users will be mapped to
>   their remote credential.  If a
>   -maproot option is given, remote access by root will be mapped to that
>   credential instead of -2:-2. If a
>   -mapall option is given, all users (including root) will be mapped to
>   that credential in place of their own.

So I used:

```
/Users/garyrichardson/leap/nfs -rw -maproot=501:501 172.16.180.130
```